# How can a web application work if I only publish the UI folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hosting

I'm still learning about MVC and following the Pro Asp.net MVC book. In the example project you create two separate projects in one solution. One is the `.Domain` project which contains db models, repositories, and context for entity framework. The second project is the `.Web` which contains the controllers, view models, views etc, they all use the `.Domain` project and I understand how it could work locally, but when publishing I only publish the `.Web` project and it somehow works. How can it use the `.Domain` classes if they are not hosted on the server?

This is the solution structure, from which I only publish the `.Web` project:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you add reference of the project `.Domain` in `.Web` and compile your `.Web` site project, it creates the `dll` of `.Domain` inside its `bin` folder. So when you deploy the `.Web` project the `dll` of `.Domain` will also be included in the project so there is no need of deploying all solution projects separately.

Comment: Oh so the goal is to deploy the project that holds all the references?

Comment: @m_bale yes and mostly its the main web project which includes all the references